# Extract data from a text file with varying column order by line

Tags: r

I have a text file named "features.txt" which has 27000 lines as below

```
E.g: first_name;30 last_name;0 height;666 gender;2    //line 1
     height;10 first_name;2333 last_name;66  // line 2
```

I also have another file featureList.txt which

```
E.g: first_name  //line 1
     height      //line 2
     last_name   //line 3
     gender      //line 4
```

What I want is "features.csv"

//column names are in order given in "featureList.txt"

```
first_name     height   last_name gender
30                666     0         2
2333               10     66        NA
```

This is what I have:

```
setwd("D:/r/social")
library(stringr)


features <- readLines("features.txt")

featuresList <- readLines("featureList.txt")

features1 <- readLines(textConnection(features, open = "r"))
featureList1 <- readLines(textConnection(featuresList, open = "r"))

fun <- function(x, y = features){
   ans <- paste(x,';\\d+',sep="")
   res <- gsub('\\D','',regmatches(y,regexpr(ans,y)))
   res
}

res <- lapply(featureList1, fun)
names(res) <- featureList1
res <- as.data.frame(result)
res


write.csv(res, "D:/r/social/features.csv", row.names=F)
```

The output I am getting is

```
Id  Choice.X0   Choice.X1
1   0.854405224 0.145594776
2   0.200898215 0.799101785
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what follows I create the vectors `features` and `featureList` using `textConnection`s, they are not read from a disk file. As for the code, all I had to do was to correct a small bug in your regular expression (add a ';') and make it into a function.

```
txt1 <-
"first_name;30 last_name;0 height;666
height;10 first_name;2333 last_name;66"

txt2 <-
"first_name
height
last_name"

features <- readLines(textConnection(txt1, open = "r"))
featureList <- readLines(textConnection(txt2, open = "r"))

fun <- function(x, y = features){
   ans <- paste(x,';\\d+',sep="")
   res <- gsub('\\D','',regmatches(y,regexpr(ans,y)))
   res
}

res <- lapply(featureList, fun)
names(res) <- featureList
res <- as.data.frame(res)
res
  first_name height last_name
1         30    666         0
2       2333     10        66

write.csv(res, "D:/r/social/features.csv", row.names=F)
```

Comment: your method didn't work.The features.txt and featureList.txt are from this link.  https://www.kaggle.com/c/learning-social-circles/data .

Comment: In order for me to download the files I need to subscribe to Kaggle. When you say it didn't work, can you be more precise?

Comment: I've just rerun my code, with the data you have provided, starting with `rm(list = ls())`, and the result is what I've posted. So there must be something else in your workspace.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyr)

# read in (you can also use readr::read_csv)
d <- read.table("features.txt",header=FALSE)

# add id so we can fold back later
d$id <- 1:nrow(d)

# separate columns, gather results in a list
L <- lapply(names(d[-4]), function(col) 
  separate_(d[c("id",col)], col , into=c("variable","value"),sep=";") )

# you can also use dplyr::bind_rows
d1 <- do.call(rbind,L)

# reshape to wide form
spread(d1,variable,value)
```